# How do insert commas into integers

Tags: java, string

If I have an integer that is 100,000

```
int integer = 100000;
```

My question is though, what if i wanted to put a comma after the first three digits so it does not look confusing and looks like `100,000`. Also if the user was to change the integer to a million for example how do i then make the code automatically put a comma after the second pair of the third digits so it looks like this `100,000,000`.

Comment: Please have a look at the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display a readable represantation of a number, you can use the following.

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(35634646));
```

```
Output: 35,634,646
```

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't allow commas, but it allows underscores for the same purpose:

```
   int integer = 100_000;

   integer = 100_000_000;
```

If you want to **output** it with commas, you have to use number formatting, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_` to separate the digits of a number in java 7.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat like this:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
System.out.print(myFormatter.format(value));
```

Please reder to this page for more info on formatters http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html